# opening and implementing a txt file into a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having problems with the following lines of code:

```
    Dictionary = {}
    with open("Text Docs/clues.txt", "r") as l:
        for l in clues:
            Dictionary[l[0]] = Dictionary[l[1]]
```

getting an error that says:

```
(file location), line #, in function
for l in clues:
NameError: global name 'clues' is not defined
```

Comment: Change `as l` to `as clues`.

Comment: spelled dictionary wrong in the program, ignore that comment

Comment: *facepalm* such an idiot

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over file object, you probably meant:

```
Dictionary = {}
with open("Text Docs/clues.txt", "r") as l:
    for line in l:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable called clues defined. The file object you created is called as l. So your for loop should iterate over that.

Use:

```
for line in l:
    #do something
```